# segmentation fault while accessing const function from inner class

Tags: c++11

Not able to understand why segmentation fault is coming while accessing const members from inner class.

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    double a;
    double b;
} conf;

class configuration
{
   public:
    configuration(const conf *conf) : conf_(conf) {}
    double
    getA() const
    {
        return conf_->a;
    }
    double
    getB() const
    {
        return conf_->b;
    }

   private:
    const conf *conf_;
};

class Test
{
   private:
    class TestInner
    {
       public:
        TestInner(const configuration *conf) : conf_(conf) {}

        void
        print()
        {
            cout << "INNER START\n";
            cout << "Innerclass data: a : " << conf_->getA()
                 << "b : " << conf_->getB() << "\n";
            cout << "INNER END\n";
        }

       private:
        const configuration *conf_;
    };

   private:
    const configuration *conf_;
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, TestInner *> TestInners;
    TestInners testInners_;
    const std::string key_;

   public:
    Test(const configuration *conf);
    void
    print();
};

Test::Test(const configuration *conf) : conf_(conf), key_("ABC")
{
    TestInner testInner_(conf);

    testInners_.insert(std::pair<std::string, TestInner *>(key_, &testInner_));
}

void
Test::print()
{
    cout << "Test data: a : " << conf_->getA() << "b : " << conf_->getB()
         << "\n";

    TestInners::const_iterator testInner = testInners_.find(key_);
    testInner->second->print();
}

int
main()
{
    conf conf_;
    conf_.a = 10;
    conf_.b = 10;

    configuration configuration_(&conf_);
    Test test(&configuration_);

    test.print();

    cout << "Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

Test data: a : 10b : 10
INNER START
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

**This seems to be compiler dependent,**

1.On g++ (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)

```
Output: 

Test data: a : 10b : 10
INNER START
Innerclass data: a : 3.15654e-317b : 6.95271e-310
INNER END
Hello World%
```

2.On Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)

```
Output:

Test data: a : 10b : 10
INNER START
Innerclass data: a : 10b : 10
INNER END
Hello World
```

3. segmentation fault in x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ (GCC) 7.4.0

Comment: Testinner on the stack in Test::Test causing ub perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the address of a variable on the stack and using the value after the method exits leads to undefined behavior.  Moving the value onto the heap, will fix the issue but require later cleanup likely in the dtor of Test

```
Test::Test(const configuration *conf) : conf_(conf), key_("ABC")
{
    TestInner testInner_* = new TestInner(conf);

    testInners_.insert(std::pair<std::string, TestInner *>(key_, testInner_));
}
```